# ForkManager (Perl) quits the parent job before the children jobs are ready

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork

I have the following perl code:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
  my $maxpro = 15;
  my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($maxpro);
my $SampId;
my $SampDir;
my $RunId;
my $Runfile;
my %hash;
 foreach $RunId(keys(%hash)) {
 $pm->start and next;
 $SampId = $hash{$RunId};
 $Runfile = $rundir . $RunId . "fastq";

 if ($SampId =~ m/16S/) {
     $SampDir = $SiXSSdir . $SampId . "_Split/"; 
 }
 elsif ($SampId =~ m/ITS/) {
     $SampDir = $ITSdir . $SampId . "_Split/";
 }
 #make a directory for each file
 my $dirouteach = $outdir . $SampId . "Single_directory.out";
 my $dirm4 = "bsub -o $dirouteach mkdir $SampDir";

 system('bash', '-c', "$dirm4") == 0 or die "Can't create each single subdirectories for either 16S or ITS, or both, see line 114" . "\n";
$pm ->finish;
}

$pm -> wait_all_children();
```

However, when i run it like this, all the children projects are running, but the main script exits prematurely, even before the children are complete, it also does not give any error message. I also tried to run it deleting `$pm ->finish;`, but in that case, the scripts is stuck and waits forever until the children are done.
I am sure i am doing something wrong with fork manager (which i never used before). My goal would be just to use it to parallelize my jobs but then wait until ALL of them are complete, and then go forward in my script.
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: At first glance your usage looks correct to me. Make sure you are using strict and warnings, and it would be better to declare your variables in the scope you need them rather than at the top of the file. e.g. `foreach my $RunId ...` and `my $SampId = ...` I assume you are populating `%hash` somehow before starting the loop?

Comment: Yes, they are populating the hash before, i didn't add it here because was not really relevant. As i wrote, the foreach loop runs smoothly, it's just that  forkmanager quits the parent while children are still running, do you guys have an idea why?

Comment: Wild guess: one of your child processes might be causing a SIGPIPE. Try setting `$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';` in the parent before your loop.

Comment: (1) Why are you using a queuing system -- is that necessary?  That can throw a wrench into just about anything, and certainly into this.  (2) Did you confirm that the child code runs correctly sequentially (or even just for one case)?  You can do that by commenting out a few lines.

Comment: @Grinnz A child cannot do much to whack a parent; if _it_ gets a sigpipe it's just gone.  Do you mean that the SIGPIPE is delivered to the parent, caused by communication between them? I don't see any comms between the child and the parent.

Comment: @zdim there's a reason I said "wild" guess :)

Comment: The `P::FM` code is fine: start a job (and skip to next), provide child code, then finish; then wait.  The question is about `bsub` and `$dirm4` program. So run the exact code that's in the child without forking first; just comment out a few lines (relating to `P::FM`). Or even just for one value, without a loop.

Comment: What's the parent's exit code? Are you using any kind of signal handlers. Please provide actual code that exhibits the problem. (See [mcve]) (I'll settle for code that exhibits the problem *for you*)

Comment: @Grinnz, A child dying from SIGPIPE won't affect the parent

Comment: Removing `$pm->finish;` is completely wrong. `$pm->finish;` is the same as `exit;`. If you remove it, the child will start executing the parent's code and stating creating children of its own.

Comment: Re "*then wait until ALL of them are complete*", That's what `$pm->wait_all_children();` does. It literally waits until all the children exit.

Answer (score 4):

`bsub` is already part of a framework for parallel computing. The `bsub` command itself runs quickly; it just submits a job to a job scheduler and exits. It it not supposed to wait for the job it is scheduling to finish, so all of your child processes should finish quickly and the main program will exit quickly, too.

If you want to control the parallel processing yourself, you should execute each command without `bsub`. If you are using `bsub`, then you shouldn't need to do your own forking or use a background process manager like `Parallel::ForkManager`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm out of ideas for debugging Parallel::ForkManager, but here's an example using [IO::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async) which is a little more flexible while similarly providing a nice wrapper around raw fork and waitpid.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Async::Loop;
use Future;

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;
my @futures;
my %hash;
... # populate %hash
foreach my $RunId (keys %hash) {
  my $dirm4;
  ... # build $dirm4
  my $future = $loop->new_future;
  my $process = $loop->open_process(
    command => ['bash', '-c', $dirm4],
    on_finish => sub { $future->done(@_) },
    on_exception => sub { $future->fail(@_) },
  );
  push @futures, $future;
}

# run event loop until all the futures are done, or throw an exception if one fails to start the command
my @exit_codes = Future->needs_all(@futures)->get;
```

You can also use [Future::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Future::Utils) to implement a queue if you don't want to start them all at once, I just recently wrote an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52613156/5848200).

Comment: thanks everyone, i learnt a lot thanks to your hints, actually it was not a problem of forkmanager, as ikegami was stating, it was ok like that, i followed @zdim hint and run the loop without forkmanager and it turn to be a variable problem (the full path to access them i didn't provide, that was the issue). thanks everyone for the precious hints anyway